# Xgboost regressor : prediction overestimated or underestimated

Tags: machine-learning, regression, xgboost

[image: Wind turbines power synthesis]

Hi,

Recently I am working on a project about synthesizing wind turbine power by the other wind turbines, like the graph above , axis X is wind turbine A power and axis Y is wind turbine B power. All the data points were derived from 10 minutes SCADA time-series data.

For now, I used xgboost regressor to predict predict the power A or B, my features are poor , power difference between A and B , wind shear , wind veer , air density and Power A/B . The metric for the model is good, but the vertical or horizontal data points which I draw the red frames in the graph make some of the predict results overestimated or underestimated since one x points or y points map to several different points.

May I ask some advice to avoid this issue ? Or Should I add some specific data engineering in addition ?

Thanks in advance .